Why $m \leq n$ in this proof of Steinitz exchange lemma?
I am trying to understand this proof of Steinitz exchange lemma on Wikipedia.
Statement:
Let $U$ and $W$ be finite subsets of a vector space $V$. If $U$ is a set of linearly independent vectors, and $W$ spans $V$, then:

$|U| \leq |W|$;
There is a set $W' \subseteq W$ with $|W'| = |W| - |U|$ such that $U \cup W'$ spans $V$.

Proof: Suppose $U = \{ u_1, \ldots, u_m \}$ and $W = \{ w_1, \ldots, w_n \}$. We wish to show that $m \leq n$, and that after rearranging the $w_j$ if necessary, the set $\{ u_1, \ldots, u_m, w_{m+1}, \ldots, w_n \}$ spans $V$. We proceed by induction on $m$.

Base case: Suppose $m$ is zero. In this case, the claim holds because there are no vectors $u_i$, and the set $\{ w_1, \ldots, w_n \}$ spans $V$ by hypothesis.


Inductive step: For the inductive step, assume the proposition is true for $m-1$.By the inductive hypothesis we may reorder the $w_i$ so that
$\{u_1,\ldots,u_{m-1},w_m,\ldots,w_n\}$ spans$V$.Since $u_m\in V$, there exist coefficients $\mu_1,\ldots,\mu_n$ such that
$$\begin{aligned}u_m=\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}\mu_iu_i+\sum_{j=m}^n\mu_jw_j.\end{aligned}$$
At least one of the $\mu_j$ must be non-zero, since otherwise this equality would contradict the linear independence of $\{u_1,\ldots,u_m\}$; it
follows that $m\leq n$ .By reordering $\mu_mw_m,\ldots,\mu_nw_n$ if necessary,we may assume that $\mu_m$ is nonzero.Therefore, we have
$$w_m=\dfrac{1}{\mu_m}\left(u_m-\sum_{j=1}^{m-1}\mu_ju_j-\sum_{j=m+1}^{n}\mu_jw_j\right).$$
In other words, $w_m$ is in the span of $\{u_1,\ldots,u_m,w_{m+1},\ldots,w_n\}$ Since this span contains each of the vectors
$u_1,\ldots,u_{m-1},w_m,w_{m+1},\ldots,w_n$ ,by the inductive hypothesis it contains$V.$

Question: I am not sure I understand how they went from "At least one of the $\mu_j$ must be non-zero" to $m\leq n.$
I tried using AI to figure out the jump, but it gives back "Now, since $\mu_j \neq 0$, the $j$-th vector $w_j$ contributes to the representation of $u_m$ in $V$. This implies that $m \leq n$, because $w_j$ (where $j \geq m$) is part of $W$, which spans $V$." Not sure how helpful it is. Maybe someone can provide a clearer explanation?

It's because the sum $\sum_{i=1}^{m-1}\mu_iu_i$ is not empty.

@CyclotomicField Thanks, although I don't see it yet. Why specifically it is non-empty and how does it follow $m \leq n$?
